# iterate through Postgres enum values?

Tags: postgresql, enum

I have a Postgres enumerated type used to describe the node class (order sensitive) of a source/destination relationship table. Question is, how can I dynamically fetch the next value (if any) of an enumeration instance?

```sql
CREATE TYPE MyEnum AS ENUM ('level1', 'level2', 'level3');

SELECT dst_type, dst_id
FROM my_relationships
WHERE src_type::MyEnum = next(dst_type::MyEnum)      -- does not work
-- WHERE src_type::MyEnum = dst_type::MyEnum + 1     -- does not work
AND src_id = 'd4fc1d5d-b054-d37c-4e80-2c04a6b3dbf8';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is anything built-in, but you can write  function to do that:

```
create function next_enum(p_current myenum)
  returns myenum
as
$$
  select t.name
  from unnest(enum_range(NULL::myenum)) with ordinality as t(name,idx)
  where name > p_current
  order by idx
  limit 1;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

Then this should work:

```
SELECT dst_type, dst_id
FROM my_relationships
WHERE src_type = next_enum(dst_type)
  AND src_id = 'd4fc1d5d-b054-d37c-4e80-2c04a6b3dbf8';
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=973783bf6182ad8a04ca0b5036b0f99f)

Comment: Nice! I did not know about the `WITH ORDINALITY` trick. Since my enums won't change I'll declare the function as `IMMUTABLE` to avoid re-computing each time.

Comment: To avoid having to maintain a `prev_enum()` function too, is there a way to define `fetch_enum(current, offset)` to be able to get the nth enumeration value away from the current where positive offsets get the next & negative ones get the previous?